# Vertically Align div within div

Tags: html, css

I've been pulling (what's left of) my hair out for a few days over this now. I've seen and tried to implement various solutions here on SO & other googlings, sadly to no avail.

I'm trying to vertically center a div within another div which is positioned using flex. Children of this div should also be centered.

I'm trying to keep the widths & heights a responsive as possible, this page will be used as a dashboard on various high-resolutions displays.

> **Similar Question** - I'm aware there is a very similar question to my own here:
>   [Vertical align fluid div within another fluid div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23518890/vertical-align-fluid-div-within-another-fluid-div).
>   I've tried to implement in my solution but it doesn't appear to make a difference. https://jsfiddle.net/AndyMeFul/Luc53a6t/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="widget-container">
<div id="widget-one" class="widget widget-prio">
    <div class="widget-header">Big Widget</div>
    <div class="widget-content-container">
        <div class="widget-textblock widget-textblock-prio">Vertically Center Me..</div>
        <div class="widget-textblock">Also me..</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="widget-two" class="widget">
    <div class="widget-header">Small Widget</div>
    <div class="widget-content-container">
        <div class="widget-textblock">And I.</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="widget-three" class="widget">
    <div class="widget-header">Empty Widget</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    margin 0;
}
#widget-container {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.widget {
    margin: 15px;
    background-color: white;
    flex-grow: 1;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.widget-prio {
    flex-grow: 3;
}
.widget-header {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
.widget-content-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
}
.widget-textblock {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.widget-textblock-prio {
    flex-grow: 3;
}
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndyMeFul/bLmy3ngq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, I'm not an expert on flex, but I think I was able to get what you wanted with this. The key was adding `height: 100%` (with a few other changes) to `.widget-content-container` although I'm not sure why a well-placed `align-items: stretch` doesn't work.

```css
body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: lightseagreen;
    margin 0;
}
#widget-container {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 0;
}
.widget {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 15px 15px 0;
    background-color: white;
    border: solid 1px black;
}
.widget-prio {
    flex-grow: 3;
}
.widget-header {
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: skyblue;
}
.widget-content-container {
    display: flex;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
.widget-textblock {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
}
.widget-textblock-prio {
    flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget-container">
    <div id="widget-one" class="widget widget-prio">
        <div class="widget-header">Big Widget</div>
        <div class="widget-content-container">
            <div class="widget-textblock widget-textblock-prio">Horizontally Center Me..</div>
            <div class="widget-textblock">Also me..</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="widget-two" class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header">Small Widget</div>
        <div class="widget-content-container">
            <div class="widget-textblock">And I.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="widget-three" class="widget">
        <div class="widget-header">Empty Widget</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Don Bottstein accepted answer. Here's a diff: Here's a Diff: https://www.diffchecker.com/txryd8s6